# Getting error while trying to connect to mysql server from sqoop

Tags: import, connect, cloudera, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

I am using cloudera CDH for practising sqoop. When I try to connect to cloudera mysql database through sqoop. I am getting error -

> "use --table or --query for import"

I followed instruction  exactly as described in the sqoop documentation.

http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server

Is there anyway to connect to mysql server from sqoop other than using the import statement.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop import --connect \
> jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera/retail_db \
> --username cloudera --password cloudera
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/07/28 07:07:31 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.5.0
16/07/28 07:07:31 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
--table or --query is required for import. (Or use sqoop import-all-tables.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqoop import` is used to import data from RDBMS to HDFS. To import data you need to tell name of **table** or **SQL query**. That's why you are getting this error:

> "use --table or --query for import"

You want to check if connection is successful with Sqoop and don't want to import data. You can try some other Sqoop features like

- **List databases**

  ```
  sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:mysql://database.example.com/ -username user --password pass
  ```
- **List tables in a database**

  ```
  sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://database.example.com/testdb --username user --password pass
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Failed to connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032: retries get failed due to exceeded maximum allowed retries number: 10

I have fixed the issue. The resource manager (YARN) was not active. Had to force start it.
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_hag_rm_ha_config.html#concept_bxf_vcx_5m